# Laravel 5 Session Flash not working in Safari

Tags: php, session, laravel, safari

I have minor security in place to not allow users to download MP3s off my site. Ajax sends a request for a token which is a one time download, this token is attached to the URL I feed into soundmanager2. This security works fine except in Safari.

Front End Request

```
streamSong: function(song)
{
$.ajax({
    url: '/streamsong/'+song.id,
    type: 'get',
    success: function(token) {
        var stream = '/streamsong/'+song.id+'/'+token;
        Player.sendSongToPlayer(song, stream);
    }
});
```

}

Route

```
Route::get('/streamsong/{id}/{token?}', 'StreamController@setupStream');
```

Controller

```
class StreamController extends Controller {

public function setupStream($id, $token = null)
{
    $stream = new Stream();

    if ($token == null) {
       if (Request::ajax()) {
            $sessionToken = $stream->setToken(str_random(40));
            return response($sessionToken);
        } else {
            return 'no way jose';
        }
    }

    if ($token ==  $stream->getToken() ) {
        return($stream->sendStream($id));
    }
}
}
```

Stream class

```
public function setToken($token)
{
    Session::flash('songToken', $token);
    return($token);
}

public function getToken()
{
    $token = Session::get('songToken');
    return($token);
}

public function sendStream($id)
{
    $post = Post::find($id);
    $pathToFile = base_path().'/storage/app/mp3/'.$post->song_path;
    $fileSize = filesize($pathToFile);
    $name = $post->song_path;
    $headers = array(
        'Content-Type'=>'audio/mpeg',
        'Pragma'=>'public',
        'Content-Transfer-Encoding' => 'binary',
        'Expires'=> 0,
        'Cache-Control'=> 'must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0',
        'Filename'=>$name,
        'Content-Length'=>$fileSize,
        'Connection'=> 'keep-alive'
    );

    return response()->download($pathToFile, $name, $headers);

}
```

The only conclusion I've come to is that Safari makes more than one request for the file download so the token is being destroyed on the first attempt. However I only see one GET request in the timeline console. If I set the Session::flash to Session::set it works fine in Safari but this bypasses the security measures. Even with Session::set I can't remove the session token variable until after the response to download has been sent out, which seems very strange.

Has anyone else experience behavior like this in Safari? I'm pretty stumped on this.

Answer (score 0):

Can you check if the browser does an OPTIONS request before it does the actual request? Sometimes this request is performed to check the capabilities of a service.

Session might also not be your best option here, you could create a JWT that hold all the information you need in its payload to stream a song once. It's easy and solid.